# GraphQL java backend getting started

Tags: java, gradle, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to make a graphQL java backend to my web application that uses Spring MVC and that I will turn in to using maven or gradle while getting all sorted out.

It feels like I have tried everything to get a backend up and running but cant manage to figure it out.

I have tried the [todomvc-relay-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/todomvc-relay-java) and when running it I just get a 415 Unsupported Media Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded when trying to get the schema and a null result when trying to get a todo or a user.

I have also tried the [spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/oembedler/graphql-spring-boot) where I can't get the dependency right when trying to include it in a project and when including the .jar files I get error because it can't find the classes that are imported. When trying to run the project as it is in terminal with gradle bootRun it get stuck at 95% and when I export it as a war file I can get the grapiql graphick running but I can't make any queries. If I try to run just the sample-app in terminal it complains about missing packages that are in the parent folder.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I fell like a moron when I can't even get a ready project up and running. Is there any easy getting started guides or anything out there that I have missed? I have googled so much but still don't find anything that gets me running I start to think that it's me that are stupid.

Comment: We have a very simple sample app using Spring MVC and graphql-spqr that you may find useful https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples

Answer (score 1):

While running the todomvc-relay-java, use this to get the schema using httpie:

`echo '{"query": "{ __schema { types { name }}}", "variables": {}}' | http post localhost:8080/graphql`

Or for curl:

`curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"query": "{ __schema { types { name }}}", "variables": {}}' localhost:8080/graphql`

Answer (score 0):

The spring-boot starter has been adopted and fixed by the graphql-java organization, so it should work for you now: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot.  If you have other issues with the starter, feel free to open up an issue on the GitHub project.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my hands on [**GraphQL-SpringBoot**](https://github.com/thekosmix/GraphQL-SpringBoot) with java using gradle, spring-jpa, spring-boot and mongo and I was able to run the GraphQL API server which had CRUD operation with authentication.
 PS: I've also attached Postman API collection links for demo.